# USB hub with 12V 5A power adapter – how can it convert the power into more amps?

Tags: current, transformer

I've found an USB 3.0 hub that has 12V 5A power adapter. USB 3.0 specification says that ports should support 0.9 A. The hub has 10 ports. Users say that it's very stable and suggest that in order to provide 9A in total the hub converts 12V to 5V with larger current. But is it possible without a transformer? Could they use some small transformer for each of the ports?

Comment: There will be one or more switching regulators in the device that utilize inductors for stepping down voltage and stepping up current. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input power limit is 12V x 5A = 60 watts.

Output power might be 10 x 5V x 0.9A = 45 watts.

This sounds like a buck regulator would eat this problem with watts of capacity to spare!

One of these would work fine: -

[image]